# Removing specific pattern from a string using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, string, pattern-matching

I am trying to remove the pattern  using following code

```
x = "mr<u+092d><u+093e><u+0935><u+0941><u+0915>" 
pattern = '[<u+0-9de>]'
re.sub(pattern,'', x)
```

Output

```
mr
```

This output is actually correct for the given sample string but when I am running this code to the corpus, it removing all the occurrences of 'de' as well as digits etc. I want these things are replaced only when < > is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `<>` outside, as the structure will always be

- start with `<`
- following by `u\+`
- 4 chars in hexa `[0-9a-f]{4}` as from Unicode definition
- end with `>`

```
pattern = '<u\+[0-9a-f]{4}>'
re.sub(pattern,'', x)
```

---

## [`REGEX DEMO`](https://regex101.com/r/cAvBoI/3) ★ [`CODE DEMO`](https://repl.it/repls/LopsidedNiftyDeadcode)

Comment: Because of `hex` characters.

Comment: @Binh This is Unicode definition. the 4 chars are hexadecimal

Comment: @Mandy8055 Oh I didnt notice it is `hex` characters, I understand it know. Thanks Mandy

Comment: @azro another doubt, As I understand {4} is used because there are always 4 characters. If the character count is not uniform we can use '|' and create multiple pattern. What will be the better way to fix this problem ?

Comment: @RajendraNayal to get an size interval do `<u\+[0-9a-f]{2,5}>` for example which accept 3-4-5 length, like 023, a5d0 and 5d9c0